# Exclude Staff Members

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `user` table:

```
id, userID, name, postcode
2   99      Bob   AAA BBB
3   8384    Jim   CCC DDD
```

And I have a `user-keys` table:

```
id, userID, keyID, val
1   435     3      1
2   773     8      0
3   99      2      1
4   99      5      1
5   99      2      1
```

Where `keyID` = 2 indicates that it is a staff member.  I want to get all the userIDs from `user` table that are not staff members.  So far I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT u.`userID` FROM `users` u
WHERE u.`userID` IS NOT NULL AND u.`userID` != 0;
```

However this does not exclude all users that have an entry in `user-keys` table with a `keyID` value of 2 and `val` of 1.

How can I perform this?

Edit: I neglected to state that any user may have multiple entries in the `user-keys` table, and I just want one list of `userID` from the `user` table, So really the results I am looking for from the above tables would simply be 8384.

Comment: Specify the SQL product that you are using.

Comment: @SankarRaj MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following join query:

```
SELECT
    t1.userID
FROM user t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT userID, keyID        -- you don't need DISTINCT here, but it may help
    FROM `user-keys`                     -- and it makes the logic a bit clearer
    WHERE keyID = 2
) t2
    ON t1.userID = t2.userID
WHERE t2.userID IS NULL
```

The logic used here is that we retain all users from the `user` table who do not appear in `user-keys` with a `keyID` of 2, or who do not appear in `user-keys` at all.

Follow the link below for a demo in MySQL.  Note that in some databases `user-keys` would not be a valid table name and would need to be escaped (I escaped above using backticks, SQL Server would use `[user-keys]`, etc.).

## Rextester

**Update:**

If you want to find only staff members, then the logic is much simpler.  In this case, we can just `INNER JOIN` the two tables together and check the status of each user:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.userID
FROM user t1
INNER JOIN `user-keys` t2
    ON t1.userID = t2.userID
WHERE t2.keyID = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited my question as I didn't word it correctly.  Please check again!

Comment: My gosh I've never seen a `LEFT JOIN ` like that.  This seems to work! Thank you! Just to double check it, how would I modify it to display ONLY staff members?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I really appreciate it.  I could not get my head around that one! I've learnt something!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user with keyID <> 2 you should use a inner join

```
  SELECT u.userID 
  FROM users u
  and u.userID  not in (select userID
    from `user-keys` 
  WHERE  keyID <>2 )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited my question as I didn't word it correctly.  Please check again!

Comment: I usually recommend `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`. (The NULL behavior when NOT IN is a bit surprising to many users...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
SELECT * FROM USER WHERE ID IN 
(SELECT ID FROM USER_KEY WHERE KEY_ID <> 2);
```

If you need all columns you can use,

```
SELECT * FROM USER U
INNER JOIN USER_KEY  UK
ON(U.ID = UK.ID)
WHERE UK.KEYID <> 2;
```